# Can't bind model to route values of DevExpress button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress

I can't seem to get a model from my view to pass back to a controller action using the route values of a DevExpress button. Here is the button:

```
Html.DevExpress().Button(btn =>
{
    btn.Name = "btnSubmit";
    btn.Text = "Search";
    btn.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
    btn.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
    btn.RouteValues = new {Controller = "ProjectSearch", Action = "PerformSearch", projectSearchParametersModel = Model};
}).Render();
```

Then I have this controller action:

```
public ActionResult PerformSearch(IProjectSearchParametersModel projectSearchParametersModel)
{ /* do search */ }
```

Unfortunately projectSearchParametersModel is null every time I get into that action and I can't figure out why the model won't pass through.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
```

example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
{
    Html.DevExpress().Button(btn =>
    {
        btn.Name = "btnSubmit";
        btn.Text = "Search";
        btn.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
        btn.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
        btn.RouteValues = new {Controller = "ProjectSearch", Action = "PerformSearch"};
    }).Render();
}
```

Comment: How would you do this in an old .ascx file instead of a razor page?